# Why do I get date does not match format error in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, valueerror, string-to-datetime

I am using to analyse a `.csv` files which only contains two columns:

- date
- time_taken

A snipped of the `csv` is:

```
date,time_taken
01-02-2019,2.3
02-02-2019,3.3
03-02-2019,2.8
04-02-2019,4.5
05-02-2019,1.2
06-02-2019,6.7
```

I am getting this `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match)
```

The `Python 3.6` snipped is:

```
import pandas as pd

transfer = pd.read_csv('tcs1_time.csv', header=None, delimiter=',')

transfer.columns = ['date', 'time_taken']

transfer['date'] = pd.to_datetime(transfer['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

The date in `csv` matches the `format`, however, I am getting this `ValueError`.

Can anyone help in this regard? thanks.

Comment: if you are reading in a csv file that has headers, you shouldn't use the "header=None" option in pd.read_csv.

Comment: I think I did that in the above code.

Comment: I'm saying that you should take out the "header=None" bit. What you are doing following your code is you are reading the first row in your file (date, time_taken) as a row in the dataframe but not as a header...this will throw an error because the string "date" will definitely not match your datetime format!

Comment: @Chilled Geek, sorry, I misunderstood you, actually it worked, that was the problem. I removed the header=None section.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Enjoy python/pandas!

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix with

```
transfer['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(transfer['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y',errors = 'coerce')
```

---

Then Using below to check what other format you have in the columns

```
transfer.loc[transfer.date1.isnull(),'date']
```

Comment: can you elaborate the issue in my code? is this Pandas' issue/bug or am I doing something wrong, I am very new to Pandas. Thanks

Comment: @DilshadAbduwali you have some value is in date columns does not have the format='%d-%m-%Y'

Comment: @DilshadAbduwali also in your csv do you have header ?, if so read it by using `pd.read_csv('tcs1_time.csv', delimiter=',')`